# How to use ceaseFire with the Endless Scroll jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

scroll jQuery plugin. Everything works fine but I can't understand the ceaseFire option.

I'd like to stop making callbacks after 10 times.

```
$(document).endlessScroll({
    fireOnce: true,
    fireDelay: 3000,
    bottomPixels: 750,
    insertAfter: "ul#articlePagedList li:last",
    loader: "<div id='processing'><img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/buttons/icon_busy.gif' alt='<spring:message code='commonMessages.loading' />' /></div>",
    callback: function(i) {
        getArticlesEndlessScroll('articlePagedList' ,'${articleListUrl}', i);
    }
});
```

I try'ed adding this but it doens't work... No errors...

```
ceasFire: function(i) { if (i==10) return true; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ceaseFire` callback doesn't receive any parameters. See the [source code for the endless-scroll plugin here](https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll/blob/master/js/jquery.endless-scroll.js). So in your function, `i` is probably undefined.

Also it's probably just a typo, but make sure you include that second `e` in `ceaseFire`.

*Example:*

```
var noneLeft = false;

$(".scroller").endlessScroll({
    callback: function() {
        $.getJSON("load_more", function(items){
            noneLeft &= items.count > 0;

            ...add items to page...
        });
    },
    ceaseFire: function() {
        return noneLeft;
    }
});
```